# Compare two Strings in javascript, obtained from a form element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, compare

I want to compare two strings in jQuery, which is very easy, but I get all the time 'yes' in the console, doesn't matter if the passwords are the same or different, any ideas? Thanks!

```
ns.resetPassword = function(){
    var password1 = $.trim($('#password1').val());
    console.log(password1);
    var password2 = $.trim($('#password2').val());
    console.log(password2);

    if(password1==password2){
      console.log('yes!');
    }else{
      console.log('different!');
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input class="form-text" id="password1" name="password.password1" type="password" maxlength="128" size="60" placeholder="@Messages("securesocial.passwordChange.newPassword1")">

<input class="form-text" id="password2" name="password.password2" type="password" maxlength="128" size="60" placeholder="@Messages("securesocial.passwordChange.newPassword2")">
```

I changed the id from password.password1 to password1 as some of you suggested

Comment: I would start by comparing with `===`.

Comment: You can only have one element per id. IDs are supposed to uniquely identify an element. I bet you are getting nothing returned as JQuery does not know what element you mean by `#password`.

Comment: Are password1 and password2 classes, or are they part of the ID?

Comment: You should have provided HTML markup, here your question is unclear

Comment: Please show HTML you are using to capture passwords.  Selectors look funny at first glance

Comment: @j08691 Oh, wow, I did not even think she was using that to identify the element. If this is true OP, you should look at Satpal's answer below. In truth though, I would recommend not using `.` in an id as that is commonly associated with a class value in CSS world.

Comment: Albeit that id's should be unique, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb4Ue/) demonstrates that what you've done should work. (It logs `different!`)

Comment: the question has been updated with the HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `===` instead of `==`

You also need to use escape `.` in selector

```
 $('#password\\.password1').val()
```

From [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYZy3/1/)

Note: In demo there are 2 function one with escape `.` and one without for comparison.

Comment: This is correct, assuming the `.` is part of the input's name (which seems a safe assumption given the look of it all, else the OP has some issues to fix in the markup naming conventions).

Comment: This answer may not be correct at all.  The === vs == will not solve the question, and without seeing the HTML we do not know that she needs to escape the period

Comment: @Satpal, only when she revealed that her id attributes were in fact password.password1 and password.password2 did this answer assuredly become correct.  Before that it was a good guess :)

Comment: @JoyRê, It was not based on assumption or guess, as `$(selector).val()` will return `undefined` if selector is not present and `$.trim(undefined)` will return `empty string` thus `yes`. otherwise there is no issue in her code. I should have added this in answer

Comment: Eh, so you saying if selectors are not present, the issue will be exactly as she described ("yes!" every time).  So all we could know is that there was no tag with id="password" class="password1".  But how do you know that the tag actually has id="password.password1" ??

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.  You can use either:

```
$('#password1').val()
```

or

```
$('input[name="password.password1"]').val()
```

to get the value in your first password input box

Comment: Hmm..I copied code to a page on my own server and it worked correctly..what is getting logged as password1 and password2 variables when you run it?